# How to post request header cookie in WebSocket javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies, websocket, header

So basically I want to get authentication with my websocket
and the authentication required cookies, 
so how can I post request my cookies into websocket in js.

here is my code

```
var uri = 'ws://' + window.location.hostname + window.location.pathname.replace('default.htm', '') + 'chat.ashx?username=' + username;
websocket = new WebSocket(uri);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361173/http-headers-in-websockets-client-api) you can't actually set headers to a WebSocket() call but you can do what you are already doing, adding arguments to the URI.

Now for cookies, they should be passed along with your call check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22285299/use-session-data-on-websocket-handshake) for more info.

Comment: [![enter image description here][1]][1]
It seems when Origin === 'protocal://' + Host, Cookie will be send automatically.


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2C1US.png